# Binding model for multiple elements

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a quite complex object which should be the model for a component.

It might look something like this:

```
{
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "value2",
    "attribute3": "value3",
    "attribute4": "value4",
    "attribute5": "value5",
    "attribute6": "value6",
    "attribute7": "value7",
    "attribute8": "value8"
}
```

This might be stored in the component in the public attribute named "iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName".

If I now have to create an input for each attribute in the model I have to write something like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute1" >
<input [(ngModel)]="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute2" >
<input [(ngModel)]="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute3" >
```

And because all the inputs are different I can't use ngFor. (in the real world, not in this example)

With the old angularJS I could do something like this:

```
<div ng-model="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName">
    <input ng-model="attribute1" >
    <input ng-model="attribute2" >
    <input ng-model="attribute3" >
</div>
```

Which you be MUCH easier and more readable.

Is there any solution for this redundant code?

I could create public attributes in the component to map the attributes, but still, the redundant code would just move from the HTML to the Typescript.

Any ideas?

### EDIT

**Thanks for the answers!**

Sorry, but it might have been unclear, but *ngFor is not working for me. Every input is completly different from the other. The example seems to have been to simple. It looks more like this:

```
<div>

    <input ng-model="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute1" type="date" >
    <input ng-model="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute2" type="number" >
    <special-input-component ng-model="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute3" >
    <div>
        <div>
            some structural information {{iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute3}}
        </div>
        <input ng-model="iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName.attribute3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case *ngFor would not help me in any way. I could work with *ngFor and *ngIf but I think this would be much more complex than neccessary.
The "old" way to change the scope for a DOM-tree element seemed to be easier for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Angular has the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe, which you can iterate object properties with `*ngFor`.

So:

```html
<div *ngFor="let val of iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName | keyvalue">
  <input [(ngModel)]="val.key">
</div>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxdvwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check my edit, the case is much more complicated.
With this solution I would have to do something like "*ngIf="val.key === 'attribute1'", which would make everything as complicated as using the whole object name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually iterate through the object keys by having a variable in the component

In the Component

```
 objectKeys = Object.keys;
 iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName= {
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "value2",
    "attribute3": "value3",
    "attribute4": "value4",
    "attribute5": "value5",
    "attribute6": "value6",
    "attribute7": "value7",
    "attribute8": "value8"
}
```

then in your html just iterate through the keys like so :

```
<div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(iHaveAVeryLongButReadableName)">
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Okay changing the html elements directly from the component shouldn't feel to you the best solution because you wanna use the angular materials to update your UI and not a method in the component, with the answer above(not mine) on changing the object proprieties those changes will reflect on the page.